# generar codigo aleatorio con mayusculas

Tags: javascript, funciones, bucle-for

Estoy intentando hacer una funcíon que genere un codigo aleatorio, lo he logrado, pero lo que no he logrado es que el codigo tenga mayusculas y minusculas..

codigo js:

```js
let abecedario =['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','ñ','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'];
function codigoAleatorio() {
  let cd='';
  for(i = 1; i<=23;i++){
    cd += abecedario[(Math.random()*(abecedario.length-1)).toFixed(0)];
  }
  return cd;
}

console.log(codigoAleatorio())
```

Ahora, hice una función que recibiera el `abecedario[(Math.random()*(abecedario.length-1)).toFixed(0)]` y que aleatoriamente ponga la letra en mayuscula o minuscula, pero no sirve casi, casi siempre o salen todos en mayusculas o todos en minusculas :c

ayudenme porfavor :c

Comment: Hola! Podes utilizar el método [.toUpperCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) ? si es así simplemente podes convertirlo al final ```return cd.toUpperCase()```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function makeid(length) {
   var result           = '';
   var characters       = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
   var charactersLength = characters.length;
   for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
      result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
   }
   return result;
}

console.log(makeid(5));
```

Esta pregunta ya fue respondida en otros idiomas y se solucionó así:

```
    function makeid(length) {
   var result           = '';
   var characters       = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
   var charactersLength = characters.length;
   for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
      result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
   }
   return result;
}

console.log(makeid(5));
```

Answer (score 2):

Me gusta tu código lo único que hice fué agregarle otra variable, Usar `if` , `Math.random` y la funcion encargada en mayúsculas `toUpperCase` .

```javascript
var abecedario =['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','ñ','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'];
function codigoAleatorio() { 
let Char;
let cd=''; 
for(i = 1; i<=23;i++){
Char=abecedario[(Math.random()*(abecedario.length-1)).toFixed(0)];
if(parseInt(Math.random()*2)==1)
cd+=Char.toUpperCase(Char);
else
cd+=Char;
  }
  
  return cd; 
 }
alert(codigoAleatorio());
```

Answer (score 0):

Una forma de lograr lo que te propones es usando las capacidades del lenguaje para representar sistemas numéricos desde base 2 hasta base 36.

El método [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/toString) *devuelve una cadena que representa al objeto* desde el que se llama el mismo. Este método puede recibir un argumento numérico que indica la base para la representación del valor del objeto. Cuando tenemos un objeto de tipo numérico, y llamamos al método `toString()` sin pasar un argumento, se devuelve la representación de dicho número en base decimal por defecto.

Por ejemplo:

```js
// un número aleatorio entre 0 y 99
let numero = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);

// representación en base 10 del número:
console.log(`Base 10: ${numero.toString()}`);

// representación en base 2 del número:
console.log(`Base 2: ${numero.toString(2)}`);

// representación en base 8 del número:
console.log(`Base 8: ${numero.toString(8)}`);

// representación en base 16 del número:
console.log(`Base 16: ${numero.toString(16)}`);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Tomando en cuenta que el valor máximo que podemos pasar al método `toString()` es 36. Esto nos da la posibilidad de obtener todos los valores numericos del 0 al 9 (10 valores) y los valores de los caracteres `a` a la `z` (26 valores).

Por ejemplo:

```js
let valores = [];
for (let i=0; i < 36; ++i) {
  valores.push(i.toString(36));
}

// usamos join(',') para mostrarlos en la misma linea.
console.log(valores.join(','));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Con esto ya tenemos una forma de generar valores numéricos y caracteres, ahora sólo hace falta convertir un carácter a mayúscula. Esto lo logramos con la función [`toUpperCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/toUpperCase) del tipo `String` de Javascript. Pero debemos hacerlo de forma aleatoria. Además para evitar la sobrecarga con [`Math.round()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/round), usaremos un truco muy simple, con el operador [*Bitwise NOT*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_NOT) de tipo lógico de Javascript. De tal forma podemos obtener los valores del 0 al 35 usando la siguiente expresión:

```
let valor = ~~(Math.random() * 36);
```

Por último podemos escribir la siguiente función, que devuelve un carácter entre 0-9 y entre a-z, y convierte de forma aleatoria el carácter a mayúscula. Usando lo que hemos visto hasta ahora:

```js
let caracter = () => {
  // obtenemos un caracter
  let char = (~~(Math.random()*36)).toString(36);
  
  // transformamos el caracter a mayúscula de forma pseudo aleatoria
  char = Math.round(Math.random()) ? char.toUpperCase() : char;
  return char;
}

// probamos una corrida de 10 iteraciones

for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  console.log(caracter());
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Ahora podemos crear cadenas pesudoaleatorias que contengan caracteres numéricos y alfabéticos en mayúsculas y minúsculas.

Supongamos que escribimos la siguiente función que devuelve una cadena de un tamaño que pasamos como argumento usando lo que hemos visto hasta ahora.

Nuestra función recibe un valor numérico que representa el tamaño de la cadena deseada y retorna la cadena pseudaleatoria esperada:

```js
// función que devuelve una cadena con caracteres
// aleatorios entre 0-9 y a-z (mayúsculas y minúsculas)
const getCadenaAleatoria = length => {
  // devuelve un caracter en mayuscula o minuscula
  const getChar = element => {
    let char = (~~(Math.random() * 36)).toString(36);
    char = Math.round(Math.random()) ? char.toUpperCase() : char;
    return char;
  }
  
  // devolvemos una cadena pseudoaleatoria
  return [...Array(length)].map(getChar).join('');
}

// tamaños de prueba
let sizes = [
  10,
  20,
  15,
  5,
  8
];

// prueba de la función
sizes.forEach(size => {
  let randomString = getCadenaAleatoria(size)
  console.log(randomString);
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.